# create rank() or row_number() column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table like below,

[image]

If we check "n" column, its double - same if Question is repeating with multiple answers separated by ansSecID.

```
QuestionId + AnsSecId = unique row
```

Can I create `rank()` column for "n". `e.g. n = 8, has 2 rows. So i want 8_1, 8_2.`

or

```
for n = 17, can I get 17_1,17_2,17_3
```

Or something like `rank()` column. `some 1,2,3 row no`. f`or repetitive n.`

max will be 3 answers for 1 question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select (cast(n as varchar(255)) +
        (case when count(*) over (partition by n) > 1
              then '_' + cast(row_number() over (partition by n order by anssecid) as varchar(255))
              else ''
         end)
        ) as new_n
```

Actually, your `repeat` column seems to do the work for the `when`:

```
select (cast(n as varchar(255)) +
        (case when repeat > 0
              then '_' + cast(row_number() over (partition by n order by anssecid) as varchar(255))
              else ''
         end)
        ) as new_n
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I am not on a computer but this should work. Could also use n for the partition

```
select Cast (n as varchar)+'-'+cast (r as varchar) str
from (
     Select n, row_number() over (partition by q_id order by anssecid) r
     from table
     ) x
```